# Emacs gives me "Latex: problems after [0] pages"

Tags: emacs, auctex

Yesterday, out of the blue, my emacs+auctex configuration stopped working and I started getting the following error when trying to do pdflatex, "Latex: problems after [0] pages".

Hitting Ctrl+C+L I see

```
Running `LaTeX' on `final' with ``pdflatex -synctex=1 -file-line-error %(extraopts) --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" /home/mdn/research/final.tex''
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -file-line-error %(extraopts) --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" /home/mdn/research/final.tex'
```

I have not been able to figure out a solution. Actually, after updating my system (to Fedora 21) my emacs has started to act a bit weirdly, with several minor glitches. If anybody could share a working, minimal, synctex-enabled .emacs file I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does the file compile if you run `pdflatex` from the command line? i.e. outside `emacs`? If not, we'll need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). If so, we need to know so.

Comment: @cfr Take a look at that command line. `%(extraopts)` hasn't been 'interpolated' (or however you want to explain the idea).  It's like an extended format code (`%s`, `%d`, `%p`, and the like) – emacs uses it for search/replace for this type of stuff.  You'll note that `sh` is the program throwing the error – the shell can't even parse the command it's being given :)

Comment: What is the value of `TeX-expand-list` for you?  Also, provide the result of evaluating `(TeX-command-expand "%(extraopts)" "test.tex")`.

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't know `emacs`. For all I know, it figures out the command to run from directives given in the `.tex` file. Of course, if you then used something different to compile at the command line you'd mask the error. But, as I say, I've never used `emacs`. (OK, once.)

Comment: @cfr Lists! Lists everywhere! :) And no worries – it was a reasonable request for clarifying information :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would search your init files for references to `TeX-expand-list`. It's possible you're removing the value, though it seems unlikely.

Next, try updating AUCTeX (`M-x list-packages`) and restarting Emacs.  Might be that simple.

If all else fails, try sticking this in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(add-to-list
 'TeX-expand-list
 (list "%(extraopts)"
       (lambda nil TeX-command-extra-options)))
```

This makes the `extraopts` key available to `TeX-expand-command`.

Comment: Adding the code you suggested to my .emacs worked, thanks!

Comment: I was having same message due to applying this solution (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72102/18414), related to `(add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
'("%(mode)"
(lambda nil
(if TeX-interactive-mode ""
" -interaction=batchmode"))))`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turned out that Emacs did not have the PATH to the 'latex' and 'pdflatex'. Just add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin/"))
```

Comment: Sorry, instead of ":/usr/texbin/" give your own path.

Comment: That path will be pretty much constant on UNIX-based systems. Do you mind if I make the code a bit more general?

Answer (score 1):

I experimented the same issue after an upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. In my case deselecting the option "Generate PDF" under the menu Command >> TeXing Options solved the issue.

Comment: That will turn off the use of `pdflatex` which is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I'm not a expert. Nevertheless in my case `pdflatex` is the command to invoke with `C-c C-c` in emacs+auctex. Turning off the `pdflatex` mode solved the issue.